# Special Struct: grouping of (pointers to function and groupings of pointers to function)

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I need to declare a "thing" that will contain a list of pointers to functions and I will need to access them in both ways:

- Directly calling to the `function.myStructVar.attr1`
- Looping through them as it were a `vector.myStructVar.vec[1]`

Therefore, I thought: "struct + union is my solution" I will declare a struct with the variables I want and afterwards a union with the struct and a vector of pointers to function.

But things has became more complicated. Now instead of having only pointers to functions, I want to mix pointers to functions with containers of pointers to functions. (I know, it is weird and I am not really clear :S)

Resuming: I want to have an grouping of (pointers to function and groupings of pointers to function). And I want to be able to access them without in a way that I do not need to know how are they structured.

Is it possible? how?

Final Objective:
I would like to have objects like:

ObjectA:

```
-Eat Apple
-Eat Bannana
--DoDigestion(this is a:
-->DigestApple
-->DigestBannana
-->AddAcid
)
```

ObjectB:

```
-Eat Potato
-Eat Bannana
--DoDigestion(this is a:
-->DigestBannana
-->AddWater
)
```

At the end, the idea is to define some kind of specification of what the is going to be done and send it to a function that will do:

Executor:

```
    void execute(Object):
       foreach(Action a in Object) do(a);
       foreach(GroupOfAction g in Object) execute(g);
```

Comment: Please make a **small** and representative example (pseudo-code if necessary) of how you want to use this.

Comment: different functions with different variable types can't be called the same. You'll have to cast to the right type before calling. But if you're ok with that, you can use templates.

Comment: I feel like using a map would be best.  You can then either look up a function by its name or iterate over the map and call each one.  Using unions does not seem like a flexible solution, changing anything would break it horribly.

Comment: Is this structure fixed or does it vary at runtime?

Comment: It will not vary at runtime, but the specifications of the app change quickely and it needs to adapt fast to them. It will be better to create something as general as possible

Comment: The executor is almost C++11. You might want to read up on the new ranged for-loop (`for (Action a : container)`. Also, we normally don't have `do` and `execute` functions; we just call them `operator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to turn your `GroupOfAction` into `Action` itself. Then give the "thing" you're looking for a `GroupOfAction`, which can now contain subgroups.

C++11 already has an "`Action`" class, `std::function<void(void)>`. So:

```
typedef std::function<void(void)> Action;
typedef std::list<Action> GroupOfAction;
Action Group(GroupOfAction const& list)
{
  return [list](){ for (Action& a : list) { a(); } }
}
```

Comment: Well, you're not exactly needing random access.